# add a close button to jquery model ( BlockUI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I used the following which works correctly but I need to have a close button rather than closing automatically how to do that? (I am using jQuery BlockUI http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#app').click(function() { 
         $.blockUI({ 
             theme:     true, 
             title:    'Welcome to your page', 
             message:  '<p>Please have a look..</p>', 
             timeout:   2000 
        }); 
    });    
});
```

Comment: favourite question cause you introduced me to a new plugin , look pretty cool

Comment: @user1537158 so give it a high rate plz

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are still interested in this, but I was looking for it and could not find it, so I had to create my own solution. You have to update the plugin though (jquery.blockUI.js), and go to this line:

```
if ( opts.title ) {
    s +=  '<div class="ui-widget-header ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all blockTitle">'+(opts.title || '&nbsp;')+'</div>';
```

and replace it with this one:

```
if ( opts.title ) {
    s += '<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">' +(opts.title || '&nbsp;')+ '</span><button id="btnCloseBlockUI" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button></div>';
```

This will add a button to the title bar. To add a button click handler:

```
//Unblocks the UI when clicking the close button
$("button#btnCloseBlockUI.ui-button").click(function () {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

You can be more fancy and add an extra option, something like `showCloseButtonUI` and display it only when it's set to true.

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but I can't get it to work right.  The button just doesn't show.

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño: Its good trick!! Button is being displayed, but click event is never fired and position of close button also messed up? Can help in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog).

The idea is to display a custom dialog, and call $.unblockUI(); when the user clicks the "No" button.